# Is the health of enemy barriers and superchargers changed in Uprising?

Tags: overwatch

In Uprising, the health of Bastion and OR-15 is massively increased, however I was wondering if any changed had been made to the OR-15's barriers and superchargers. I've only encountered the enemy superchargers once or twice, and haven't really noticed how much HP they have, so I was wondering if they too have been granted more health.